# Find higher api 23 calls than minSdk 21

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

Hello there are some answer on this topic, but none which worked for me so far.
My build.gradle looks like this

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
 minSdkVersion 21
 targetSdkVersion 23
```

Somewhere in my Fragments I called the method `getContext()` and that crashed the app on a Lollipop 5.0 device. It works fine on Marshmallow 6.0.

The `Fragment` is imported from the non support library package.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

and since I have compileSDK on 23 I can call the method `getContext()` withing the Fragment to get the [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).
This will lead to a crash on Lollipop 5.0 and 5.1 since that method was added with API 23 and not API 21,22.

My Question is, how can I find such high level calls in Android Studio when the min SDK is below that?

Comment: Maybe `getContext()` was only an example, but `getActivity()` is the appropriate substitute for API < 23

Answer (score 3):

> how can I find such high level calls in Android Studio when the min
>   SDK is below that?

AFAIK Android studio normally warn the developer whenever they are using any methods which is not completely backward compatible till minSDKVersion defined by the application. So, At that point of time, you can check out current version of device and call relevant other method accordingly.

However, for some reason its not showing any lint warning while calling `getContext()` method. So, It seems we have to deal with it now.

Comment: There is a possibility to run an explicit check for incompatible calls. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Go to

-> Analyze -> Inspect Code -> run code inspection

Then in the result view there is

```
"Project Name"
    - Android > Lint > Correctness
        - calling new methods in older versions
```

Under (**calling new methods in older versions**) all unavailable calls should be listed

Answer (score 0):

Now that we're in 2022, I found a more appropriate solution.
Run the `gradlew lint` command in *Terminal* and waiting for it to finish will generate a report file.

```
Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Users/Administrator/path/to/project/module/build/reports/lint-results-$flavorName$buildType.html
```

open this file in browser, find `InlinedApi` and `NewApi` and you will find all of it.